# How can the Eclipse toString code generator be changed to display less verbose Calendar objects

Tags: java, eclipse

The Eclipse toString source generator is extremely helpful except when objects contain a Calendar object. Is there a way to change the Eclipse toString generator to display Calendar objects more cleanly? 
Possibly using a common SimpleDateFormat?
Or a trustworthy plugin?

Desired Calendar toString ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):

```
2011-08-22 13:29:26
```

Sample Eclipse Calendar toString (this is pretty ridiculous):

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1314034166984,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2011,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=35,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=22,DAY_OF_YEAR=234,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=1,HOUR_OF_DAY=13,MINUTE=29,SECOND=26,MILLISECOND=984,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

FuryComputers led me to a solution. Here is a quick and dirty Custom toString implementation:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MyToStringBuilder {
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    private String str;
    private boolean isFirst;

    public MyToStringBuilder(Object o) {
        isFirst = true;
        str = "";
        str += o.getClass().getSimpleName() + " [";
    }

    public MyToStringBuilder appendItem(String variableName, Object value) {
        if(value != null){
            this.addItem(variableName, value.toString());
        } else {
            this.addItem(variableName, "null");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public MyToStringBuilder appendItem(String variableName, Calendar value) {
        if(value != null){
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            this.addItem(variableName, sdf.format(value.getTime()));
        } else {
            this.addItem(variableName, "null");
        }
        return this;
    }

    private void addItem(String variableName, String value) {
        if(!isFirst){
            str += ", ";
        }
        isFirst = false;
        str += variableName + "=";
        str += value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        str += "]";
        return str;
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Tell the world to decide on a time standard that makes more sense

Comment: #WORLD: Decide on a time standard that makes more sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generate a toString method in eclipse, the dialog has a "Code Style" option. In that list is "Custom toString() Builder" which you can define your own String Builder type class to use.

It is (poorly) documented here under "Custom toString() builder"
http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-tostring-styles.htm

Answer (score 6):

The following effectively overwrites the toString() method for any class as seen using the Eclipse Debugger only, but I've found it very useful in decoding calendar objects while I debug.

Add a Debug Detail Formatter, using these steps:

1. From the menu select Windows->Preferences
2. In Preferences open Java->Debug and click on Detail Formatters
3. Here you can add your desired formatter

As an example, for the calendar object:

1. Click Add..
2. Enter java.util.Calendar into the Qualified type name field
3. Enter the following:

   java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
   sdf.format(this.getTime());
4. Ensure Enable this detail formatter is checked
5. Click OK.

(Source: http://acoderslife.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/eclipse-java-debugging-showing-variable-type-values-calendar/)

Comment: I thought the question was regarding toString; does this also change how the toString generator works?

Comment: Good point.  This only changes how toString works wrt the Eclipse debugger.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful! Debugging Calendars is always an issue.

Comment: You forgot to consider timezones. In step 3, should use: `java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"); sdf.setTimeZone(this.getTimeZone()); sdf.format(this.getTime());`

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse just uses the GregorianCalendar.toString() method. The only way to change this would be to extend the GregorianCalendar class in your own Object and implement a custom toString() method.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class MyGregorianCalendar extends GregorianCalendar
{
    public MyGregorianCalendar() {
        super();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:MM:d kk:m:s");
    public String toString() {
        return sdf.format(getTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - I'd rather not change the underlying data model so a toString can work. This would also cause some additional complications with javax.persistence.

Comment: Agreed it's ugly but that's the way around it if it's important to you.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of toString() is to give a string representation of the objects state.  This is great for debugging and logging.

Except for the simplest cases in which the format of an object is well defined, it should not be used as a UI type label.  There is no contract for toString() which will guarantee consistent results or format.  If you want a specific type of output from an object for user display purposes, then code a method specifically for that.  Don't use toString() for it.

In the OP's specific case, there are a dozen different ways to represent a date.  That is why there are date formatting classes to present consistent output.

Comment: I definitely don't want toString for client use but I do want it for logging and debugging - and the Calendar.toString is excessively verbose for that purpose (and as such violates Oracle's definition of toString: "The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read."). I am looking for a tool (in Eclipse or as a plugin) for creating toString methods with 'concise but informative' Calendar class output.